# How to rename a product variation attribute in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

All the products in my woocommerce site have an attribute 'Color' which is also used for creating variations for the products. This variation comes by default when I import any new product and I dont have any control over it. I want to make this variation appears as something like 'Color/Variant' on the site front end while it should be unaltered in the backend. How can I achieve this in custom code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (in your *functions.php* file)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'rename_color_attribute_label', 10, 3);

function rename_color_attribute_label($label, $name, $product){
  if(strtolower($label)=='color'){
    $label = 'Color/Variant';
  }
  return $label;
}
```

Comment: no need to mess with code on this one. (see answer below from Jean). you can change the name of the variation via wp-admin without affecting the slug

Answer (score 1):

No need for coding. Simply go to PRODUCTS in left column, and then in the dropdown choose ATTRIBUTES. That will also give you access to changing the names of variations.

Comment: This is actually the quickest and best way to do it IMO. I would ALWAYS back up the database before making changes like this though.

Comment: It seems that editing the attribute names actually resets the attribute for each variation, so this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

WRONG. Once you save the attribute (like if you forget to capitalize it) there is no way to remove it or change it. Fix this WOOCOMMERCE. You just get the stupid error message "blue already exist in the taxonomy".

Answer (score 0):

There are two places you can manage the attributes - one is under WooCommerce tab on the left in wordpress dashboard. But there's another place you can manage inside the product itself - in the product data section - under "shipping" and "linked products." This was what threw me off. Once I opened *that* attributes menu, I saw I could add the new attribute there.

**HOWEVER**, as HXT Sauce mentioned, when you go to change a name, it actually won't really change the name but puts in a new variation (or it might update the one you had but it's not clear which one that is or you won't realize till you go to edit the new variation). So you'll need to write down what the stock amount & details were before changing the name. Then, after changing the name, you'll need to "add manually" a new variation. It will then produce a blank variation for you to select the new one from the list & edit the details there. This is somewhat confusing. Probably not much less confusing than this explanatory note I'm posting (^_^).